# How to fill a datatable or dataset with an AWS ATHENA query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, aws-sdk, amazon-athena

I'm trying to solve an app with asp.net c#, i need to query an S3 bucket with AWS ATHENA, and my problem is to fill a datatable or a dataset with the query result.

Comment: Are you asking how to call Amazon Athena from a C# app?

Comment: Please, elaborate a bit more. What do you need to get from Athena? What do you need to put into Athena? how?, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class I wrote to do this a while ago

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Amazon;
using Amazon.Athena;
using Amazon.Athena.Model;
using Services.Common.Authentication.Interfaces;
using NLog;

namespace My.Services
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides the ability to run queries against AWS Athena
    /// </summary>
    public class AthenaService
    {
        private const int SLEEP_AMOUNT_IN_MS = 1000;
        private IAmazonAthena _amazonAthenaClient;
        private readonly IAwsCredentialsService _awsCredentialsService;
        private readonly IAmazonAthenaFactory _amazonAthenaFactory;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        //IOC calls this constructor
        public AthenaService(IAthenaSettings athenaSettings, IAwsCredentialsService awsCredentialsService, IAmazonAthenaFactory amazonAthenaFactory, ILogger logger, AwsKeys awsKeys)
        {
            AthenaSettings = athenaSettings ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(athenaSettings));
            _awsCredentialsService = awsCredentialsService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(awsCredentialsService));
            _amazonAthenaFactory = amazonAthenaFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(amazonAthenaFactory));
            _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
            if (awsKeys == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(awsKeys));
            }
            Authenticate(awsKeys);
        }

        private void Authenticate(AwsKeys awsKeys)
        {
            try
            {
                var regionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(AthenaSettings.RegionEndpoint);
                if (regionEndpoint.DisplayName == "Unknown")
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("RegionEndpoint not correctly specified in AthenaSettings configuration");
                }

                _amazonAthenaClient = _amazonAthenaFactory.Create(_awsCredentialsService.GetCredentials(awsKeys.AwsAccessKey, awsKeys.AwsPrivateKey), regionEndpoint);
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                _logger.Error(e.ToString());
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.Error(e.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }

        ///<inheritdoc />
        public async Task ExecuteNoResultsAthenaQueryAsync(string queryString)
        {
            var uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
            _logger.Trace($"Running query '{uniqueId}'\r\n{queryString}");
            var queryExecutionId = await SubmitAthenaQueryAsync(queryString);
            _logger.Trace($"Waiting for results of query '{uniqueId}'");
            await WaitForQueryToCompleteAsync(queryExecutionId);
            _logger.Trace($"Query finished '{uniqueId}'");
        }

        ///<inheritdoc />
        public async Task<List<T>> ExecuteAthenaQueryAsync<T>(string queryString, Func<ExpandoObject, T> rowParser)
        {
            var uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
            _logger.Trace($"Running query '{uniqueId}'\r\n{queryString}");
            var queryExecutionId = await SubmitAthenaQueryAsync(queryString);
            _logger.Trace($"Waiting for results of query '{uniqueId}'");
            await WaitForQueryToCompleteAsync(queryExecutionId);
            _logger.Trace($"Query finished '{uniqueId}', obtaining results");
            var items = await GetQueryResultsAsync<T>(queryExecutionId, rowParser);
            _logger.Trace($"Query results available for '{uniqueId}'");
            return items;
        }

        ///<inheritdoc />
        public IAthenaSettings AthenaSettings { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the query results and parses them into a List<T>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="queryExecutionId">The query queryExecutionId to get results for</param>
        /// <param name="rowParser">A func that is capable of parsing the Athena row into a T</param>
        private async Task<List<T>> GetQueryResultsAsync<T>(string queryExecutionId, Func<ExpandoObject, T> rowParser)
        {
            var items = new List<ExpandoObject>();
            var getQueryResultsRequest = new GetQueryResultsRequest()
            {
                QueryExecutionId = queryExecutionId,
                MaxResults = 1000
            };
            GetQueryResultsResponse getQueryResultsResponse;

            do
            {
                getQueryResultsResponse = await _amazonAthenaClient.GetQueryResultsAsync(getQueryResultsRequest);
                for (int i = 1; i < getQueryResultsResponse.ResultSet.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    var eo = new ExpandoObject();
                    var dict = (ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>)eo;
                    for (int j = 0; j < getQueryResultsResponse.ResultSet.ResultSetMetadata.ColumnInfo.Count - 1; j++)
                    {
                        dict.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(
                            getQueryResultsResponse.ResultSet.ResultSetMetadata.ColumnInfo[j].Name,
                            getQueryResultsResponse.ResultSet.Rows[i].Data[j].VarCharValue));
                    }
                    items.Add(eo);
                }
                if (getQueryResultsResponse.NextToken != null)
                    getQueryResultsRequest.NextToken = getQueryResultsResponse.NextToken;
            }
            while (getQueryResultsResponse.NextToken != null);

            var returnResults = new List<T>();
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                returnResults.Add(rowParser(item));
            }
            return returnResults;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Submits a sample query to Athena and returns the execution ID of the query
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="queryString">The query to run</param>
        /// <returns>QueryExecutionId</returns>
        private async Task<String> SubmitAthenaQueryAsync(string queryString)
        {
            // The QueryExecutionContext allows us to set the Database.
            var queryExecutionContext = new QueryExecutionContext()
            {
                Database = AthenaSettings.DefaultDatabase
            };

            // The result configuration specifies where the results of the query should go in S3 and encryption options
            var resultConfiguration = new ResultConfiguration()
            {
                OutputLocation = AthenaSettings.AthenaQueryOutputBucketLocation
            };

            // Create the StartQueryExecutionRequest to send to Athena which will start the query.
            var startQueryExecutionRequest = new StartQueryExecutionRequest
            {
                QueryString = queryString,
                QueryExecutionContext = queryExecutionContext,
                ResultConfiguration = resultConfiguration
            };

            var startQueryExecutionResponse = await _amazonAthenaClient.StartQueryExecutionAsync(startQueryExecutionRequest);
            return startQueryExecutionResponse.QueryExecutionId;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Wait for an Athena query to complete, fail or to be cancelled. This is done by polling Athena over an
        /// interval of time. If a query fails or is cancelled, then it will throw an exception
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="queryExecutionId">Query id to wait for completion on</param>
        private async Task WaitForQueryToCompleteAsync(String queryExecutionId)
        {
            var getQueryExecutionRequest = new GetQueryExecutionRequest()
            {
                QueryExecutionId = queryExecutionId
            };

            var isQueryStillRunning = true;
            while (isQueryStillRunning)
            {
                var getQueryExecutionResponse = await _amazonAthenaClient.GetQueryExecutionAsync(getQueryExecutionRequest);
                String queryState = getQueryExecutionResponse.QueryExecution.Status.State.ToString();
                if (queryState.Equals(QueryExecutionState.FAILED.ToString()))
                {
                    throw new InvalidProgramException($"Query Failed to run with Error Message: {getQueryExecutionResponse.QueryExecution.Status.StateChangeReason}");
                }
                if (queryState.Equals(QueryExecutionState.CANCELLED.ToString()))
                {
                    throw new InvalidProgramException("Query was cancelled.");
                }
                if (queryState.Equals(QueryExecutionState.SUCCEEDED.ToString()))
                {
                    isQueryStillRunning = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Sleep an amount of time before retrying again.
                    await Task.Delay(SLEEP_AMOUNT_IN_MS);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```